# TypeScript 'Dictionary' type accessors for objects vs objects with known members?

Tags: typescript

I'm learning TypeScript following an online video course -- I come from a background in 'structurally' typed languages (C, ActionScript 3), but some of the things in TypeScript are new to me.

In particular I'm trying to understand the 'dictionary' type of Object.

```
interface dict {
  [accessString: string]: {
     name: string;
     address: string
  } | undefined
}
```

So what I'm saying here is that an object that adheres to his interface will accept access such as

```
const userData = myObject['someString']
const userData2 = myObject.someString
```

and `userData` and `userData2` would be the same object, which contains the fields `name` and `address`, right?  Or this field might not exist on the object, in which case we'd get `undefined`?  (Which is why it's necessary to add `| undefined` to the interface definition?).

OK.  But how does that differ, conceptually, from the definition of an object interface like the following?

```
interface notDict {
   someString: {
         name: string;
         address: string
}
```

In this case we're saying that we *know* that there's a field called `someString` on the object, whereas with our original 'dictionary-type' definition we weren't expressing any opinion about what the fields would be?  Are there other differences between the `[accessString:string]:{}` definition and a `plain object` definition?  Or am I not seeing this correctly?

Thanks for any guidance!

Comment: One more detail is that the dictionary type says there's 0 or more keys while when you explicitly state the keys you're also explicitly stating how many members the object will have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically got it all down. Biggest differences are:

1. `interface Dict` allows you to name the parent object any name you want, whereas `interface notDict` enforces the name of the parent object to be `someString`.
2. `Dict` types can be an empty object, `notDict` types require all fields at all times.
3. Once you define a `Dict` type to be a non-empty object, all fields are required. (you can get around this by using `?` after the key (ex. `name?: ...`).

See examples [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCbAWZBvAUM5AbUSQGdSBlMKUAcwC5lTq6BdRvArkOAWwkbMaIWgG58XZHFSooEcoJYiJAX2QAfZAFcQqCDFARUuFblyhIsRChAB7MABEMWTgVK3+VYQxwTJ3PgEmJTE-fykZOQVg7zC1AhMzBFsQZikARkZ0TGQAXhxkAHpC5Kg5HK1SOFoIMIAjABs4AAsOIsKpEABPZB5+ZAB3WygAa1IwyT6ggHJ+qemAGgmuaVl5UkZZlFWoabjE3GTUrDgAJiznPJw1YuRS8qxK6qCEOBBkOpQIXgAHMB7bHUAFYQHKfV6VFC2GDIABEmh0egMICMsOQoGQYGaKAs0HgSCSKTScAAzBccvlXAQ3l0vHQAHKBNq3FJIZCAkE5YCkND6QyoBZSBoNZAjCBdHlwOTIOQARy0wDkxnCBCmm2xwtse0kplMhyJWDqmV69icFIKt3uoMeVRqYXcnhCbWWqqZyGmcF6gUWLoia2iHsi2q4usJxw+5xNjkulPtHggdJEzI6vG5pDoMog8sVRmQBggDVQ7p262myAAFMAAHQQKtCkX5wuS6VyhVKgCUvrVxa9-GDBFD+vDdTJUbNWFjkgGUBStETPmw7UGM5E87Qtnk4GQEAAHtysBi7NHMF23R7exAfSq-VENsWg-s9UA).

Comment: Thanks -- in your example, when you have `const a3: dict = {
    anyStringName: {
        name: 'hello'
    }
}   // once object is defined, all keys are required`-- what does 'all keys are required' mean here?

Comment: It means the keys `name` and `address` from object `anyStringName` are required.